# Как написать aiogram бота на вебхуках?

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram, heroku, webhook

Я перерыл весь интернет в поисках информации по созданию телеграм бота с помощью AIOGRAM(а не telebot) на webhook, но ничего не нашёл.
Я пытался как то сделать это и выложить на heroku, но у меня естественно не получилось.
Может кто-нибудь подробно рассказать как создавать телеграм бота на AIOGRAM c webhook с последующим деплоем на heroku?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Зачем вам вебхуки и на хероку? Хероку отлично работает с полингом, по слухам, на хероку нужно фиксить траблы с постоянным засыпанием бота если он на вебхуках. Во всяком случае сыль:https://habr.com/ru/company/ods/blog/462141/  - и да, вы можете попробовать настроить вебхуки на других библиотеках, а после с легкостью понять как это делается на айограм.

Comment: Это более чем хорошо описано в примерах из документации - https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/webhook_example.html . Фактически нужно заменить  только `executor.start_polling` на `executor.start_webhook()`, да реализовать две функции - `on_startup()` и `on_shutdown()`, внутри которых вызывать регистрацию вебхука(`bot.set_webhook()`) при старте и его удаление при остановке бота(`bot.delete_webhook()`)